# SW6.5 App Redirect to Frontpage or Search Page after 404

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I was trying several ways including the Resources/views/storefront/page/error/error-404.html.twig and Resources/views/storefront/page/error/_page.html.twig to get this redirect to work, but I failed:

```
{% set redirectUrl = path('frontend.home.page') %}
{% set response = redirect(redirectUrl) %}
{% set status = 302 %}
{% do app.close(response, status) %}
```

[image]

All I get is a blank body page, with header and footer. In the header there is the Home button only, no other menu entries.

[image]

What do I do wrong here? I just like to redirect to the front page or product search, instead of showing the 404 error page.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, didn't see app tag  Well, simply said: You currently can't do it programmatically, as you could with plugins. I guess you could [use javascript to redirect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp), that should work by extending the template.

```js
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "https://example.com";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("https://example.com");
```

I'll leave the original answer for plugin developers.

##### For plugins

You can create a [custom subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) that listens to exception events. That listener can have a higher priority than the default listener and as such prevent the default listener from being called. Then you can create a `RedirectResponse` to be used in case of `HttpException` instances with the 404 status.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Subscriber\MyErrorSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SwagBasicExample\Subscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class MyErrorSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly RouterInterface $router
    ) {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        // priority higher by one than the default error listener
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['onError', -99],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onError(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();
        if (!$exception instanceof HttpException || $exception->getStatusCode() !== Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
            return;
        }

        // stop the default listener from being called afterwards
        $event->stopPropagation();
        
        $response = new RedirectResponse(
            $this->router->generate('frontend.home.page'),
            Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
        );

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is simply working well 

        <script>
            window.location.replace("{{ path('frontend.home.page') }}");
        </script>